# Android Studio - Unable to build project - GradleConnectionException

Tags: android, android-studio, build.gradle, android-gradle-plugin, gradlew

I'm on Android Studio 0.3.2. Since I upgraded from previous version, unable to build existing projects.

I'm consistently having gradle integration problems.
I spend more time sorting out gradle than writing any code.
I've been stumped for one week now!

I get the error mentioned on so many posts, but after reading for hours none of the solutions have worked for me.

org.gradle.tooling.GradleConnectionException: Could not execute build using Gradle installation 'C:\Users\Adrian.gradle\wrapper\dists\gradle-1.8-all\2kopnp0i5dq014k75fp36m3vd5\gradle-1.8'.: Could not execute build using Gradle installation 'C:\Users\Adrian.gradle\wrapper\dists\gradle-1.8-all\2kopnp0i5dq014k75fp36m3vd5\gradle-1.8'.

I checked my gradle version using the built in terminal window in android studio.

[image: gradlew --version in terminal window]

My gradle.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project version="4">
  <component name="GradleSettings">
    <option name="linkedExternalProjectsSettings">
      <GradleProjectSettings>
        <option name="distributionType" value="DEFAULT_WRAPPED" />
        <option name="externalProjectPath" value="$PROJECT_DIR$" />
        <option name="useAutoImport" value="true" />
      </GradleProjectSettings>
      <GradleProjectSettings>
        <option name="distributionType" value="DEFAULT_WRAPPED" />
        <option name="externalProjectPath" value="D:\Users\Adrian\AndroidStudioProjects\SupaScaleProject" />
        <option name="useAutoImport" value="true" />
      </GradleProjectSettings>
    </option>
    <option name="serviceDirectoryPath" value="$USER_HOME$/.gradle" />
  </component>
</project>
```

My gradle-wrapper.properties

```
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=http\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-1.8-all.zip
```

My build.gradle

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.6.+'
    }
}
        apply plugin: 'android'

   repositories {
        mavenCentral()
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 18
    buildToolsVersion "18.1.1"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 18
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            runProguard true
            proguardFile getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt')
        }

        debug {
            runProguard false
            proguardFile getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt')
        }
    }

 }

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:13.0.+'
    compile files('libs/achartengine-1.1.0.jar')
}
```

I do a build from the Terminal: gradlew compileDebug and the build is successful!

[image]

Now I build form the Menu bar Build -> Rebuild Project (in AndroidStudio 0.3.2):

[image]

I really don't know where to look anymore.
Any help will be appreciated.

Oh .. yes I have deleted all the files in .gradle/wrapper/dists/ and allowed Android Studio to download for me.

Thanks in advance.

Adrian

Following **@joucks** comment, I noticed the following at http://tools.android.com/knownissues:

[image]

So I changed my build.gradle to `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.6.3'` unfortunately still the same result.

Thereafter I updated the compileSDKVersion to 19, and the buildToolsVersion to "19.0.0", hoping for some success. Unfortunately none. Yes .. and before you ask, my SDK-Manager is up to date with all the latest files.

Comment: just want to mention, that I can do a **gradlew compileDebug** from Terminal, then **gradlew installDebug** to install on my device, and the program works as expected.

Comment: No I didn't Erik. I unistalled the lot, and moved all my project to 0.3.6 I was still getting odd gradle errors, then used Analyze, inspect code, and started on the top of the list and worked my way down, until it eventually compiled. I had for one some drawables (icons) that were missing in a layout that was unused, but was still causing a failure. So all I know, it is BETA, and the gradle error reporting is still very poor.

Comment: if you problem is solved plz mark the solution and answer your question.

Answer (score 1):

I finally figured this one out.  Both times this has happened to me, rebooting my computer made it go away.  "GradleConnectionException" must happen because of some memory leak or resource issue in windows.

Comment: for me, i had to go to the command line and kill the GradleDaemon process. rebooting would have accomplished the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

To quote the Android Studio 0.3.2 [release notes](http://tools.android.com/recent/androidstudio032released) and the [details](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide#TOC-Using-sourceCompatibility-1.7):

> You also need to make sure that Gradle is using version 1.7 or later
>   of the JDK. (And version 0.6.1 or later of the Android Gradle plugin.)

And you are using `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.6.+'`. It might be related.

Comment: I'm using JDK 1.7.0_05 and 0.6.+ will use the latest if I understood correctly, and no need to put 0.6.1 ...

Comment: Actually the correct version would be 0.6.3, but using 0.6.+ will select for 3 confirmed by Google in a bug report. This however does not take away the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this post:
https://plus.google.com/+AndroidDevelopers/posts/1RcQews58tB
A few guys report there that deleting gradle-1.8 and .gradle folder seems to fix the problem.
Also, as far as I recall, problem may reooccure if there are some memory shortage issues.

Edit:

That's the thread: http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=61259

Answer (score 0):

In my case, After down-grading jdk from 1.7 u51 to 1.7 u45, all work fine.

I guess that gradle 1.8 checks revision number of JDK.